# Java - Explicit Conversion from Int to Short

Tags: java, variables, casting, int, short

Can someone please explain why this following statement:

```
short value = (short) 100000000;
System.out.println(value);
```

Gives me:

```
-7936
```

Knowing that the maximum value of a short in Java is 32767 correct?

Comment: i get -7936 when i run the same code

Comment: Sorry, it's supposed to be 1000000

Answer (score 25, accepted):

With your value of 100 million, I get -7936.  I can only get 16960 if I change 100 million to 1 million.

The reason is that `short` values are limited to -32768 to +32767, and Java only keeps the least significant 16 bits when casting to a `short` (a [narrowing primitive conversion, JLS 5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)).  Effectively this operation: 1 million mod 2^16 (16 bits in a `short`) is 16960.

Answer (score 3):

The way you did it merely reinterprets a smaller number of bits at the same memory location. It does not change them.

You probably want to use the `max` and `min` functions to detect when the value lies beyond of `short` and assign the max or min value of the short when that happens.

```
int n = 1000000;
short value = n > Short.MAX_VALUE ? Short.MAX_VALUE : n < Short.MIN_VALUE ? Short.MIN_VALUE : (short)n;
```

**Update:** more compactly:

```
import static java.lang.Math.max;
import static java.lang.Math.min;

// ...

value = (short)min(max(value, Short.MIN_VALUE), Short.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println(value);
```

Comment: @AppXene "it merely reinterprets a smaller number of bits starting from the same memory location"

Comment: Please delete this it does not answer the question - you'll get your rep back

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D looks like i got my rep back, and then some more :D

Answer (score 3):

[Here's](http://www.myhowto.org/java/60-understanding-the-primitive-numeric-type-conversions-in-java/) good article explaining narrowing and widening primitive conversions in Java.

> ```
> short s = 696; // 0000 0010 1011 1000
> byte x = (byte)s;
> System.out.println("byte x = " + x);
> ```
>
> Produces:
>
> ```
> byte x = -72
> ```
>
> Now you should understand why - because when we narrow short down to
>   the byte the JVM discards the most significant part (00000010) and the
>   result (in binary form) is 10111000. This is the same number we were
>   looking at before. And, as you can see, it is negative, unlike the
>   original value.