# Please explain conversion from int to short

Tags: java, casting, int, short

Can anyone please explain to me:

```
    short s = 0;
    int x = 07;
    int y = 06;
    int z = 123456;

    s= (short) z;
    System.out.println(""+s);

    System.out.println(" "+x+y+s);
```

Output is

```
-7616
76-7616
```

Please explain.

Comment: What do you not understand?

Comment: why am i getting output -7616. can u plz explain the math behind it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overflowing Short in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11990681/overflowing-short-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - Explicit Conversion from Int to Short](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860817/java-explicit-conversion-from-int-to-short)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`123456` in hex is `1E240`.

Since a short only has room for two bytes, you lose that first hex digit and end up with `E240`.

`E240` in binary is `1110001001000000`, hence it is a two's-complement negative number. To find the (absolute) value of the negative number represented by that, you invert the digits and add 1.

`0001110110111111` is `7615`, add `1` and you get `7616`.

That is why you are seeing `-7616`.

More about two's complement here: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html