# Does casting random integers to short give a uniform distribution?

Tags: java, random, casting, int, short

As the title explains, I am looking to generate a series of random short values. Because there is no Random.nextShort() function, the easiest way to do what I want seems to be to cast integers to short, using:

```
Random rand = new Random(int seed);
(short) rand.nextInt()
```

However, I don't fully understand how this casting takes place, and so I cannot be sure that the resulting short values would still be random. Is this the case? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way is to do `short result = (short)(rand.nextInt(Short.MAX_VALUE-Short.MIN_VALUE+1) + Short.MIN_VALUE)`. The reason for this is that you want a number from a range that spans `Short.MAX_VALUE-Short.MIN_VALUE+1` values, and starts at `Short.MIN_VALUE`.

Simple truncation may be enough fort `short` *(and if speed matters to you, it's probably also faster)*, but this approach works for any range.

Let's say you want a random number between `-5` and `12` (both inclusive), you will then call `rand.nextInt(12-(-5)+1)+(-5)`, or if you simplify all the calculations: `rand.nextInt(18)-5`.

Answer (score 4):

A short cast of an int works by bitwise truncation. As long as the integers are randomly distributed, the short values should be also - yes.

From the Java Language Specification [5.1.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3):

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T
>   simply discards all but the n lowest order bits, where n is the number
>   of bits used to represent type T.

`int` has 32 bits, `short` has 16. Essentially the conversion is the same as adding (or subtracting) 65536 (which is 2 to the power of 16) until the value is in the range representable by `short`. Thus, there are exactly 65536 `int` values which map to each possible `short` value.

Answer (score 1):

A good solution to avoid error is :

```
Random rand = new Random(int seed);
short s = (short) rand.nextInt(Short.MAX_VALUE + 1);
```

If you also need negative short :

```
short s = (short) rand.nextInt(Short.MAX_VALUE - Short.MIN_VALUE + 1) + Short.MIN_VALUE;
```

A fastest solution :

```
short s = (short) random.nextInt(1 << 16); // any short
short s = (short) random.nextInt(1 << 15); // any non-negative short
```

Answer (score -1):

The number will be still random, but you can have problem with different max/min values of this number, for more info, look at first answer here [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860817/java-explicit-conversion-from-int-to-short)

Answer (score -1):

I think this will not work because an `int` is a lot bigger than a `short`.

Just take a random `float` or `double` (the values are between [-1;1]) and multiply them by the max value of a short:

```
short i= (short) rand.nextFloat() * Short.MAX_VALUE;
```