# How to convert double array to short array in java?

Tags: java, android, double, short

I have array of double in java and I need to convert into array of short. Any idea?

Comment: You should provide more detail in your question, what problem are you facing, how do you want to handle values that are to large, rounding etc.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson . I have to play the array using audio track and it accepts short

Comment: You may get a different value for any number beyond the max and min value a `short` variable can hold. Check https://stackoverflow.com/q/18860817/10819573 to understand it.

Comment: That wasn't much of a clarification.

Answer (score 2):

```
    double[] d = { 2, 3.2, 4.8, 123456789.123 };
    short[] s = new short[d.length];
    
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
        s[i] = (short) d[i];
    }
    System.out.println("short output: " + Arrays.toString(s));
---------------------
Result: short output: [2, 3, 4, -13035]
```

Is that really what you need? Is the precision loss not important for you?

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to print it...?
You can cast your double to a short when printing a single value from the array like this:

```
    public class array {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        double [] array = new double[] {132.45612, 9556.456789876, 6513.987652, 123456789.123};
        System.out.println((short)array[3]);
    }
}
```

This outputs `-13035`

By changing the number in the sysout, you should get a different result.